# Pesonalized links list

Tags: list-view, 2016, hyperlink

I want to create at list of links for my Company intranet FrontPage in SP 2016. Each user has to be able to add links and be able to see only the links they added themselves.

I tried creating a list view and sort it so elements only appear if the "created by" column equals [Me]. Apparently there exist an unresolved bug with the [Me] filter which causes it to not Work.

Is there another way to make this kind of list?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried my links https://mylinks.codeplex.com (note this link may not work later as codeplex is shutting down)?  This gives a small UI to create/manage personal links. Although it was built for SharePoint 2010 but should work on 2016.

[image]

[image]

[image]